# How do you save data from inputs into a list then print them separately without knowing exactly how many inputs are saved

Tags: python

So i have this code for a restaurant kind of code and i have to reuse the inputs over and over sometimes and i need to store all of them in a list or something of sorts so that i can later print it in the order review/checkout section. The below is my code and currently im using orderreview to store my stuff but its not really working. its the list. then i have the function at the bottom called DisplayOrderReview which is printing all of the data out of the list but i can't figure out how to make this work. the display order review function needs to print the price of each have the quantity of each menu item and the menu item itself as well as if you wanted the additional ingredients. im able to make it save only one set of data from each input before it doesnt do what i want it to do.

```
`
total = 0

# Function to display the menu options
def menuscreen():
    global name
    print("Welcome!")
    print("Entrée:")
    print("1 for Butter Chicken - $20")
    print("2 for Rogan Josh - $18")
    print("3 for Bombay Grilled Chutney Sandwich - $16")
    print("4 for Spicy Pork Vindaloo - $21")
    print("Main:")
    print("5 for Beef Enchiladas - $25")
    print("6 for Beer and Brown Sugar Kielbasa & Sauerkraut - $19")
    print("7 for Coconut Shrimp with Mango Dipping Sauce - $20")
    print("8 for Crab Cakes with Remoulade Sauce - $18")
    print("9 for Greek Lamb Gyros with Tzatziki Sauce - $21")
    print("Dessert:")
    print("10 for Self-saucing chocolate pudding - $16")
    print("11 for Gin and tonic tart with candied lemon - $15")
    print("12 for Matt Moran's Gaytime trifle - $18")
    print("13 for Cream Brulee - $15")
    print("14 for Kremes - $14")
    print("-------------------------")
    #asks for users name
    print("Thank you for dining with us! What is your name?")
    name = input("==>")
    print("Nice to meet you "+ name)

#what you want to order
def orderselection():
    global item
    global price
    global total
    global orderreview
#error handling/validifying
    while True:
        try:
            OrderItem = int(input("What would you like to order? "))
            if OrderItem < 1 or OrderItem > 14:
                raise ValueError("Invalid menu item")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 14.")
#order choices numbers 1 to 14 = item
    if OrderItem == 1:
        print("You've selected Butter chicken")
        item = "Butter Chicken"
        price = 20
    elif OrderItem == 2:
        print("You've selected Rogan Josh")
        item = "Rogan Josh"
        price = 18
    elif OrderItem == 3:
        print("You've selected Bombay Grilled Chutney Sandwich")
        item = "Bombay Grilled Chutney Sandwich"
        price = 16
    elif OrderItem == 4:
        print("You've selected Spicy Pork Vindaloo")
        item = "Spicy Pork Vindaloo"
        price = 21
    elif OrderItem == 5:
        print("You've selected Beef Enchiladas")
        item = "Beef Enchiladas"
        price = 25
    elif OrderItem == 6:
        print("You've selected Beer and Brown Sugar Kielbasa & Sauerkraut")
        item = "Beer and Brown Sugar Kielbasa & Sauerkraut"
        price = 19
    elif OrderItem == 7:
        print("You've selected Coconut Shrimp with Mango Dipping Sauce")
        item = "Coconut Shrimp with Mango Dipping Sauce"
        price = 20
    elif OrderItem == 8:
        print("You've selected Crab Cakes with Remoulade Sauce")
        item = "Crab Cakes with Remoulade Sauce"
        price = 18
    elif OrderItem == 9:
        print("You've selected Greek Lamb Gyros with Tzatziki Sauce")
        item = "Greek Lamb Gyros with Tzatziki Sauce"
        price = 21
    elif OrderItem == 10:
        print("You've selected Self-saucing chocolate pudding")
        item = "Self-saucing chocolate pudding"
        price = 16
    elif OrderItem == 11:
        print("You've selected Gin and tonictart with candied lemon")
        item = "Gin and tonic tart with candied lemon"
        price = 15
    elif OrderItem == 12:
        print("You've selected Matt Moran's Gaytime trifle")
        item = "Matt Moran's Gaytime trifle"
        price = 18
    elif OrderItem == 13:
        print("You've selected Cream Brulee")
        item = "Cream Brulee"
        price = 15
    else:
        print("You've selected Kremes")
        item = "Kremes"
        price = 14

# Ask for quantity
def quantity():
    global amount
    while True:
            try:   
                amount = int(input("How many would you like? (Max 50) "))
                if amount < 1 or amount > 50:
                    raise ValueError("Invalid amount")
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 50.")

def extraingredients():
    global price
    global total
    global amount
        # Ask for additional ingredients
    print("Any additional ingredients for $5? (Y/N) ")
    additionalingredients = input("==>")
    if additionalingredients.upper() == "N":
        ingredients = "No"
        total = total = 5
    elif additionalingredients == "Y":
        ingredients = "Yes"

    # Calculate total and update order review
    item_total = price * amount
    total += item_total
    orderreview[item] = {
        "quantity": amount,
        "add ingredients": ingredients,
        "price": item_total
    }

    # Ask if user wants to order something else
    orderagain = input("Would you like to order something else? (Y/N) ")
    if orderagain.upper() == "Y":
        return orderselection()
    elif orderagain == "N":
        DisplayOrderReview()

# Function to display the order review
def DisplayOrderReview():
    print("Your order review:")
    for item, details in orderreview.items():
        print(f"{details['quantity']} x {item}")
        if details['add ingredients']:
            print(f"   Additional ingredients: {details['add ingredients']}")
            print(f"   Price: ${details['price']}")
            print(f"Total: ${total}")

def PayCancelRestart():
    global PCR
    print("Type 1 to pay")
    print("Type 2 to cancel your order")
    print("Type 3 to Restart your order")
    print("-------------------------")
    while True:
        try:   
            PCR = int(input(""))
            if PCR < 1 or PCR > 50:
                raise ValueError("Invalid Option")
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Please enter a number between 1 and 3.")
    if PCR == 1:
        pay()
    elif PCR == 2:
        goodbye()
    elif PCR == 3:
        restart()




def pay():
    print("Type Pay to pay")

def restart():
    global total
    dict.clear(orderreview)
    total = 0

def goodbye():
    global name
    print("Thank you for your order, " + name +"!")

menuscreen()
orderselection()

`
```

in the details of the problem above.

Comment: [Do not mark your question as "urgent"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing the menu in a `list` of `dicts`, as I think this will make your life easier.

I am using `decimal` below to ensure you do not have any unexpected imprecision errors from using `float`.

I have not put in your full menu for brevity reasons. (There are enough items to demonstrate the concept.)

I have not implemented all of your functions from your code above, as I'm sure you can adapt from the core ordering process (which is where I think you were having issues) below:

```
import decimal

MENU = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Butter Chicken",
        "price": decimal.Decimal(20),
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Rogan Josh",
        "price": decimal.Decimal(18),
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Bombay Grilled Chutney Sandwich",
        "price": decimal.Decimal(16),
    },
]

MENU_ITEM_COUNT = len(MENU)
ADDITIONAL_INGREDIENTS_COST = decimal.Decimal(5)
order = []


def welcome():
    print()
    print("Welcome!")
    name = input("Please enter your name > ")
    print()
    print(f"Nice to meet you {name}.")
    print("What would you like to order?")


def order_item():
    print()
    for i in MENU:
        print(f"{i['id']} for {i['name']} - ${i['price']}")
    print()
    while True:
        try:
            selection = int(input("What would you like to order? > "))
            if 1 <= selection <= MENU_ITEM_COUNT:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print(
                f"Invalid option: please enter a number between 1 and {MENU_ITEM_COUNT}."
            )
    selection -= 1
    print(f"\nYou selected: {MENU[selection]['name']}")
    while True:
        try:
            qty = int(input("How many would you like (max 50)? > "))
            if 1 <= qty <= 50:
                break
            else:
                raise ValueError
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid option: please enter a number between 1 and 50.")
    while True:
        ai = input(
            f"Any additional ingredients for ${ADDITIONAL_INGREDIENTS_COST}? (Y/N) > "
        ).lower()
        if ai == "n" or ai == "y":
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either Y or N")
    order.append(MENU[selection])  # Append item dictionary to order list
    order[-1:][0]["qty"] = qty  # Add qty value to dictionary in order list
    order[-1:][0]["ai"] = "Yes" if ai == "y" else "No"  # Add whether additional ingredients are wanted to dictionary in order list


def order_again_query():
    while True:
        print()
        another_order = input(
            "Would you like to order something else? (Y/N) > "
        ).lower()
        if another_order == "n" or another_order == "y":
            break
        else:
            print("Please enter either Y or N")
    return another_order


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        welcome()
        order_item()
        while order_again_query() == "y":  # Keep asking for item order until user enters "n" at the prompt
            order_item()
        # Process order
        print()
        print('---- Order Summary ----')
        total = decimal.Decimal(0)
        for item in order:
            print(
                f"{item['name']} x {item['qty']} @ ${item['price']} each. Additional Ingredients: {item['ai']}"
            )
            total += item["price"] * item["qty"]
            if item["ai"] == "Yes":
                total += item["qty"] * ADDITIONAL_INGREDIENTS_COST  # Add ai cost per item
        print(f"Total: ${round(total, 2)}")
        print('-----------------------')
        order.clear()
```